# Java parse HTML Code to Selenium Webelement

Tags: java, html, selenium

Is there mybe a way to paste HTML code to a Selenium Webelement?
Sure i could just use the driver to to get the page HTML and than could use
driver.findelement().

But is there mybe a way to parse the HTML data to the Element like
Webelement myelement = new Webelement(HTML_STRING)?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Give us more details, more specifics on what you are trying to do. A clear example would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do: element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");

But I think you have something else in mind, what are you trying to do with this?.